# Multi monitor navigator software

Tags: display, window-manager, multi-monitor

I have lots of monitors, 3 monitors + 1 tv. Sometimes when I work in for example Photoshop, I open a dialog window or get a error message popup, but this window may appear on a different monitor that might be turned off, usually the TV. So in those cases I have to turn on the TV to move it back to my active monitor. I can also use Shift+Windows+Arrow key but only if I didn't click something else after the window opened. Sometimes a popup window appears without me noticing, so I click around and then notice there's an error somewhere that I first have to find to close it. Leaves me no choice but to turn on the tv and find it. Pretty annoying and time consuming, it breaks the work flow.

This wouldn't have to be the case if there was a software that gives me a miniature view of all monitors where I can move around any window opened between the monitors.

Consider this overview of multiple monitors:
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/Z1vKieb_aRrXJGA4uXg-pcrpnndQBoSWKAD6jXtRhpj3yAl81F5Yoc8iuGXFoLlqQViHAG-YCLBrUyJLkTdqaDClaWXStLorS0q_szii9A-s_XPkenDqVn-Nq4v6mXM9YoRnFojzilMpBMjNVA

What if I could interact and drag around the windows inside of the overview where it says 1, 2, 3?
Then I can leave some monitors off and still be able to access any popup that accidentally opens there.

I can usually use the Shift+Win+Arrows for the whole application but for smaller panels and dialog boxes I usually run into trouble.

So some sort of multi monitor navigator or window manager that's has a miniature preview of all monitors where I can move around windows and apps. All windows including small dialog boxes.

Hope I made an understandable explanation.

Thanks in advance!
Cheers!